# Manage shader alpha and depth

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, alpha, depth

I've an object. I'm applying a plane on it. This plane defines which pixels I want to be visible and the other have to be invisible.

Here it's the object with an other point of view. We see the object is cut on his left.

[image: Here it's the object with an other point of view. We see the object is cut on his left.]

---

Here is the object see from the plane point of view. The plane has already cut some part of the object. But we see that these parts are always here because they hide the other part of the object.

[image: Here is the object see from the plane point of view. The plane has already cut some part of the object. But we see that these parts are always here because they hide the other part of the object.]

---

The big problem is I can't change dynamically the opacity of an object at runtime without putting an alpha pragma to my shader code. But this alpha pragma break all my object with some artifacts because Unity is unable to manage Fade & ZDepth. I mean when you've an opaque shader, it's different from the same shader but with pragma alpha. (no alpha change in Editor or whatever).

Here is an example of result to just put alpha pragma in my shader code.

[image: Here is an example of result to just put alpha pragma in my shader code.]

---

I just want an "opaque" object (and my CutPlane works well with it) but change the opacity dynamically too.

If someone has an idea :) Thanks

EDIT : Shader code

```
Shader "Custom/Clipping" {


    Properties {
      _Conversion ("Conversion (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}     
      _MainTex ("Main Texture", 2D) = "white" {}            
      _NormalxValue("Normal X Value", Float) = 1        
      _Glossiness ("Smoothness", Range(0,1)) = 0.5          
      _Metallic ("Metallic", Range(0,1)) = 0.0      
      _Color ("Color", Color) = (0.5,0.5,0.5,1)
    }
    SubShader {
      Tags { "Queue" = "Transparent"  "RenderType" = "TransparentCutout" "DisableBatching" = "True" }
      LOD 200

      Cull Off

     Pass {
        ZWrite On
        ColorMask 0

        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag
        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        struct v2f {
            float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
        };

        v2f vert (appdata_base v)
        {
            v2f o;
            o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos (v.vertex); //o.pos = 0 ==> no Depth

            //Here I know that if I put o.pos = 0; Zbuffer is desactivate.
            return o;
        }

        half4 frag (v2f i) : COLOR
        {
            return half4 (0,0,0,0);
        }

       ENDCG  
    }


      CGPROGRAM

      #pragma surface surf Standard alpha
      #pragma target 3.0

      struct Input {
          float2 uv_MainTex;    
          float2 uv_BumpMap;        
          float2 uv_Conversion;     
          float3 worldPos;          
      };    

      half _Glossiness;
      half _Metallic;
      half _ConvertDistance;
      half _ConvertEmission; 
      fixed4 _Color;

      ////////////////////// 
      /// <Cut Area
      //////////////////////
      float3 _PlaneNormal;

      //Plane variables
      float _xValue;
      float _yValue;
      float _zValue;

      float _NormalxValue;
      float _NormalyValue;
      float _NormalzValue;
      ////////////////////// 
      /// Cut Area />
      //////////////////////

      ////////////////////// 
      /// <Interest Area (sphere)
      //////////////////////

      sampler2D _MainTex;
      sampler2D _BumpMap;
      sampler2D _Conversion;

      void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o) {

        _ConvertDistance = 0.4;
        _ConvertEmission = 0.45;
        _PlaneNormal = float3(_NormalxValue,_NormalyValue,_NormalzValue);
        _PlaneNormal = normalize(_PlaneNormal);

        // Calculate distance from object to plane
        half dist = (IN.worldPos.x * _PlaneNormal.x) + (IN.worldPos.y * _PlaneNormal.y) + (IN.worldPos.z * _PlaneNormal.z)
                    - (_xValue * _PlaneNormal.x) - (_yValue * _PlaneNormal.y) - (_zValue * _PlaneNormal.z) 
            / sqrt( pow(_PlaneNormal.x, 2) + pow(_PlaneNormal.y, 2) + pow(_PlaneNormal.z,2));

        float convert_mask = dist / _ConvertDistance;

        if(any(dist < 0))
        {
            discard;
        }
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        o.Albedo = _Color;
        o.Metallic = _Metallic;
        o.Smoothness = _Glossiness;
        o.Alpha = _Color.a;   

      }
       ENDCG
    } 
    // Si pas de subshader possible - On appelle un shader Diffuse.
    Fallback "Diffuse"
  }
```

Comment: do you try it by stencil buffer? can I see your shader code?

Comment: yeah I try stencil, but I'm not familar with it so it's difficult.

Edit in my question ==> Shader code

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question in case someone has the same problem.

The problem was I calculate my Cut plane for the color with the wolrdPosition of my object and for the ZBuffer I did the same but with ClipPos Position.

Add this line in vertex function :

```
o.worldPos =  mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, v.vertex);
```

And use it to calculate. Don't use ClipPos given by

```
o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos (v.vertex);
```